# Wrapping a row in a background color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've not thought about this massively and I'm probably missing something very obvious but how does one properly apply background colours to '.row'

[image: Background applied to columns leaves inconsistencies]

The code I've been using:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 white-flood">
    </div>
</div>
```

However this only applies to columns. I've tried wrapping them in a div, applying the style to the .row class among other things

Thanks :)

EDIT:

This should help people find out what my issue is (applying to .row should do the trick but something in my code is stopping it from working). The 4 thumb links should have awhite background.

[Click here for site](http://hub.yfish.co.uk/temp/bootstrap/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added position: relative to my flood class and it worked...

I believe it is something to do with my responsive  background intefering.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1) Set the background color to the row:

```
<div class="row white-flood">
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
</div>
```

2) You need to use table layout

```
<div class="row" style="display: table">
    <div class="col-lg-4 white-flood" style="float: none; display: table-cell"></div>
</div>
```

But this will slightly break the bootstrap design, as the table cant have a negative margin.

Comment: Tried the first method originally but that didn't work ever and I've no idea why. I haven't tried the second option but I've built a few pages now so I don't want to do something that could break everything :(

Comment: I started again and stripped everything out and just had the basic bootstrap files. Applying a flood to the row then worked. SO there is something in my site not allowing it to work. I'll look into it myself and will upload my files soon for people to check - :)